# What is the ratio distribution of two independent gaussian variables with DIFFERENT means?

Tags: probability, gaussian

Specifically, I am interested in exploring what happens at the upper and lower tails of the distributions. Is a small difference in means amplified at the extremes? Where does the ratio peak? What is the rate of change as the measured value increases toward infinity?

Comment: The answer will also depend on the variances.

Comment: You can have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Uncorrelated_noncentral_normal_ratio)